# TSOA parameter serialization

Tags: swagger, tsoa

Is it possible to use [Swagger Parameter Serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization) options with TSOA annotations or change default serialization in global config?

I have an API, that has an query property of type array, something like:

```
public async getUsers(@Query('status') status?: UserStatus[])
```

That produce something like:
https://user.service/api/users?status=ACTIVE&status=BLOCKED&status=PENDING

But i want it comma separated:
https://user.service/api/users?status=ACTIVE,BLOCKED,PENDING

Thanks!